# Not able to add marker on Google map

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am developing an application that requires marker to be placed on Google map. The click event is recognized when I run the code in chrome. However, the touch event is not recognized in the android device that I am testing the code on.

I am using Ionic, AngularJs and Cordova for hybrid app development.

My controller looks like this :

```
.controller('Map', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, uiGmapLogger,sharedProperties){

uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }, zoom: 16 };
$scope.models = [];

$scope.events = {
    click: function (map, eventName, handlerArgs) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.models.push({
                id: $scope.models.length,
                latitude: handlerArgs[0].latLng.lat(),
                longitude: handlerArgs[0].latLng.lng(),
            });
        });
    }
};

});
})
```

The html file looks like this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events="events">
  <ui-gmap-markers models="models" coords="'self'" options="'options'"></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Can somebody provide me a work around for this issue? I would greatly appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Setting the coords as map center did the trick ! :D

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events="events">
  <ui-gmap-marker coords="map.center" idkey="1" ng-cloak>

        </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```